# css not picking images from absolute path

Tags: css

My directory structure is

```
MyPhoto
MyPhoto/css/myPhoto.css
MyPhoto/images/fatherday1.jpg
```

In the css, I have defined following class

```
.jumbotron-welcome {
    background-image: url('../images/fathersday1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    color:white;
}
```

I notice that 
`url('../images/fathersday1.jpg');` works but 
`url('/images/fathersday1.jpg');` doesn't.

Should `/images/..` path work? I suppose `MyPhoto` directory is root of my project and it has `images` folder.

Comment: Are you looking at these on a server or just opening the HTML file directly in the browser? If it's the latter, absolute paths won't work (but they should start working once you upload to a server). Also is MyPhoto your webroot, or is it just a directory IN your webroot? Again, if it's the latter, you need to include it in your absolute path, i.e. `/MyPhoto/images/fathersday1.jpg`

Comment: @delinear : late by 5secs, was about to post literally the same stuff!!!

Comment: its only HTML in a browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain:

`../` means "go up one dir from where you are now". Your current working directory is `css`. You go up on, and then enter `images`. This is a legit path.

When you start your resource with `/`, you start from the document root. You may see `/` as `http://example.com/`. So you are at the document root and try to enter `images`. But that doesn't exist. You first have to go into `myPhoto`: `url('/myPhoto/images/fathersday1.jpg');`

*Please note that this is based on a simple server setup. If you use a more complex parser, the actual needed path may differ, but the logic remains. Figure out where the path `/` really starts.*

Comment: additional factor is, who is parsing this path? is it the client or the server, this too matters a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I think this will help you.

[image: Sample CSS]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with `"/"` returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with `"../"` moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with `"../../"` moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
- To move `forward`, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward